# Trouble assigning value to BOOL

Tags: objective-c

It seems simple, but I don't know why its not working.

In my .h file I have declared: `BOOL keyboardIsUp;`

And then in my .m file:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow {

    NSLog(@"before:");
    NSLog(keyboardIsUp? @"Yes" : @"No");

    NSLog(@"keyboardWillShow");
    keyboardIsUp = YES;

    NSLog(@"after:");
    NSLog(keyboardIsUp? @"Yes" : @"No");

    ...
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide {

    NSLog(@"before:");
    NSLog(keyboardIsUp? @"Yes" : @"No");

    NSLog(@"keyboardWillHide");
    keyboardIsUp = NO;

    NSLog(@"after:");
    NSLog(keyboardIsUp? @"Yes" : @"No");

    ...
}

-(BOOL)keyboardStatus{
    NSLog(@"keyboardStatus");

    NSLog(keyboardIsUp? @"Yes" : @"No");

    return keyboardIsUp;
}
```

The methods are definitely being called correctly (I can see this from the NSLog messages) and with my `NSLog` messages within the first 2 methods, I can see that the BOOL is set correctly (within the scope of the function).

But when I call `keyboardStatus`, it always Logs "NO"

Any ideas?  I've scoured the rest of my code I am definitely not changing the value of `keyboardIsUp` anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are talking to the correct instance of your object?

I.e. add this to the beginning of each method:

```
NSLog(@"[%@(%p) %@]", self, self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

If the hex number changes between `keyboardWillHide/Show` and `keyboardStatus`, then you are talking to different instances.   If not, something else is going on.

Comment: The hex value did indeed change between the `keyboardWillHide/Show` and `keyboardStatus`.  So I guess I am not talking to the same instance of my object.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd bet you have one instance loaded from a XIB file and you are allocating/initializing a second instance in your code.   Eliminate the manually allocated instance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're not calling them on the same object?